# Using Python Flask, mod_wsgi, apache2 - unable to get custom 500 error page

Tags: python, apache, wsgi, flask

I am running Ubuntu, Flask 0.8, mod_wsgi 3 and apache2.  When an error occurs, I am unable to get Flask's custom 500 error page to trigger (and not the debug mode output either).  It works fine when I run it without WSGI via app.run(debug=True).

I've tried setting WSGIErrorOverride to both On and Off in apache settings but same result.

Anyone has gotten this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the error is actually coming from Flask if you are getting a generic Apache 500 error page? You should look in the Apache error log to see what error messages are in there first. The problem could be configuration or your WSGI script file being wrong or failing due to wrong sys.path etc.

Comment: I checked the apache error log and I see the uncaught python exception - and it's not a wsgi setup issue

Comment: FWIW, hop on #pocoo on IRC where Flask guys hang out and you might get a quicker response. The question has been asked there before, but just can't remember the required voodoo. I am pretty sure it is documented on Flask site as well somewhere.